# Passing a list of values back to controller

Tags: java, grails, groovy, gsp

I have the following problem

1. I'm creating a `List<UserProfileHelper>` of values
2. This list is added to the ProfileUserCommand to be sent to the view (profile.gsp) for rendering

As you can see, the ProfileUserCommand object includes 2 boolean values, intended to control the status of the checkboxes in the GSP. This part works perfectly, as I can see the GSP rendered correctly, and with checkboxes properly marked/unmarked.

When submitting the form back to a controller, I don't know how to "rebuild" this list with the updated values from the GSP, so I can have a `List<UserProfileHelper>` of updated data.

These are my classes

**UserProfileHelper.groovy**

```
class UserProfileHelper {

    Long optionId
    String optionName
    boolean isSubMenu
    boolean hasAccess
    boolean canWrite

}
```

**ProfileUserCommand.groovy**

```
class ProfileUserCommand {

    String username
    List userProfile = [].withLazyDefault { return new UserProfileHelper() }

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false
        userProfile blank: true, nullable: true
        access blank: true, nullable: true
    }
}
```

**profile.gsp (only the relevant section of the GSP)**

```
<g:each in="${command.userProfile}" var="option">
    <tr>
        <td>
            ${option.optionId}
        </td>
        <td>
            <g:if test="${!option.isSubMenu}">
                ${option.optionName}
            </g:if>
            <g:else>
                &nbsp;
            </g:else>
        </td>
        <td>
            <g:if test="${option.isSubMenu}">
                ${option.optionName}
            </g:if>
            <g:else>
                &nbsp;
            </g:else>
        </td>
        <td>
            <g:checkBox bean="${option}" name="access" value="${option.hasAccess}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <g:checkBox bean="${option}" name="write" value="${option.canWrite}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</g:each>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the command to the parameters of your controller method.

E.g.:

```
class YourController {
  def submitAction(ProfileUserCommand command) {
    // do something with command
  }
}
```